# Как wget'ом скачать документ вк?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Когда получаю ссылку на документ через api vk, даётся не прямая ссылка на него, а какая то левая (если это изображение), wget не может скачать его, но если в браузер её вставить то перенаправляется на документ. Как wget'ом скачать это?

пример как я делаю

```
elif item['attachments'][0]['doc']['title'][-4:] == '.png':
                commands.getoutput('wget -O in.png ' + item['attachments'][0]['doc']['url'])
```

непрямая: https://vk.com/doc333762526_445867303?hash=dc8fb03b38014898f3&dl=FUYTGMBZHAYDSOJX:1496487173:e55d0227cc0cf560bd&api=1&no_preview=1

прямая: https://psv4.userapi.com/c812639/u333762526/docs/a1eef5324a4d/out.png?extra=QHyn0neMwwB4pY2tiq4yrNYLOUA5EkoVhvcBWdi1uR0dR_hu1JW7QxUUp2TrSVhoqCcf3Yi9blYAQ4sB_mbMWIHz5osucrfK7KJraSOTXaxK6w0YZRHPvNDSOw

Comment: Пример ссылки? Что там такого 'левого', javascript что ли?

Comment: Дополнил примерами

Comment: @Gleb По второй (прямой) ссылке 404. Видимо, потому что нужен ваш аккаунт в ВК. Но, я могу вручную взять прямую ссылку из непрямой.

Comment: В вашем вопросе не указана метка языка -- шансов, что кто-то найдёт ваш вопрос в текущем виде особо нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте окружить адрес в кавычки:

```
commands.getoutput("wget -O in.png '" + item['attachments'][0]['doc']['url'] + "'")
```

Но вы точно хотите вызывать внешнюю команду? Вместо того, чтобы это делать с помощью какой-нибудь библиотеки? Например так (для 3+):

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
urlretrieve ("https://vk.com/doc...", "in.png")
```